# A little advice on using the chain rule for differentiation

Tags: calculus, derivatives, chain-rule

I must be a little rusty, but how would I evaluate the following:

$$
\frac{d}{dr}\left(1-\frac{b(r)}{r}\right)^{-1}
$$

My stickler is that $b$ is a function of $r$...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply power rule outside, then chain rule for ecpression inside bracket.

Then apply quotient rule on $\dfrac{b(r)}{r}$, then again chain rule on $b(r)$
$$\frac{d}{dr}\left(1-\frac{b(r)}{r}\right)^{-1} = -1\left(1-\frac{b(r)}{r}\right)^{-2}\cdot(-1)\cdot\left(\dfrac{r\cdot\dfrac{d}{dr}b-b(r)}{r^2}\right)$$

$$=\dfrac{r\cdot\dfrac{db}{dr}-b(r)}{(r-b(r))^2}$$

Comment: Just a thought, but since I do not know what $b(r)$ is explicitly, should I just wait until it is known, at which point I can evaluate it as above. But until that point should it just not stay in the form that you have on the LHS of the above line...?

Comment: @MichaelRoberts it is always good to simplify the expression. Derivative of just the function $b(r)$ remains unknown, and can be substituted to get the result!

Comment: So would it be better practise not to evaluate this differential until b(r) is known explicitly?

Answer (score 4):

You could write

$$\left(1-\frac{b(r)}{r}\right)^{-1}=\left(\frac{r-b(r)}{r}\right)^{-1}=\frac{r}{r-b(r)}$$

Thus, we differentiate using the quotient rule and chain rule. We express the derivative of $b(r)$ as $b'(r)$. An alternate notation is $b'(r)=\frac{db}{dr}$.

$$\left(\frac{r}{r-b(r)}\right)'=\frac{r-b(r)-r(1-b'(r))}{(r-b(r))^2}=\frac{rb'(r)-b(r))}{(r-b(r))^2}$$

Comment: Much better ..!

Comment: Thank you! Personally, I hate expressions to the negative first power!

Comment: I hate these expressions to negative powers, with functions inside them. Very complex! Thank you for the help, which answer should I accept?

Comment: Nice catch! Fixed!